# i want to make a chart by age group

Tags: sql, oracle

[image: member table]

member table

```
`select age, count(*) as "the number"
from (select floor((to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') - substr(birth, 1, 4)) / 10) * 10 as age from member) 
group by age order by age asc;`
```

**how to get data**

[image: when there is 10's data]

when there is 10's data.

[image: where there is no 10's data]

when there is no 10's data.

i want to print even when there is no data in 10's group.

for example,

age / the number

10  / 0

20  / 4

30  / 4

40  / 0

50  / 0

60  / 3

how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0c9134c1b82edf5abaefa3b044a58145)

```
select grp.age, COALESCE(val."the number", 0) as "the number"
from (
    select 10 as age FROM dual UNION ALL
    select 20 FROM dual UNION ALL
    select 30 FROM dual UNION ALL
    select 40 FROM dual UNION ALL
    select 50 FROM dual UNION ALL
    select 60 FROM dual UNION ALL
    select 70 FROM dual UNION ALL
    select 80 FROM dual UNION ALL
    select 90 FROM dual UNION ALL
    select 100 FROM dual
) grp
left join (
    select age, count(*) as "the number"
    from (select floor((to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') - substr(birth, 1, 4)) / 10) * 10 as age from member) 
    group by age 
) val ON grp.age = val.age
order by grp.age asc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Only using current year and birth year will not always give you the correct age. If you want to find the correct age then use `MONTHS_BETWEEN`:

```sql
select age,
       count(*) as "the number"
from   (
  select floor(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, birth) / 120)) * 10 as age
  from   member
) 
group by age
order by age asc;
```

If your `birth` column is a string then convert it to a `DATE` using `TO_DATE` (but, really, you should fix the column data type rather than parsing the string):

```sql
select age,
       count(*) as "the number"
from   (
  select floor(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, TO_DATE(birth, 'YYYY.MM.DD')) / 120)) * 10 as age
  from   member
) 
group by age
order by age asc;
```